# Ruby gsub pattern

Tags: ruby

I have the following string:

`Rib Franzido - La Mandinne`

I need to change the spaces to dash (-):

`blusa-rib-franzido-la-mandinne`

But using gsub I got this:
`blusa-rib-franzido---la-mandinne`

Code:
`string.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-')`

How can I solve that?
Thanks

Comment: You say: _"I want to change the spaces to dash"_ and this is exactly what your code does. Try to describe the desired outcome with more details. This exercise tells you what code to write.

Answer (score 4):

Just squeeze the dashes:

```
"Rib Franzido - La Mandinne".tr(" ", "-").squeeze("-")  # => "Rib-Franzido-La-Mandinne"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be one way to do it using regex that first replaces spaces between words, then another gsub to remove other spaces.

```
"Rib Franzido - La Mandinne".downcase.gsub(/(?<=\w)\s(?=\w)/, '-').gsub(' ', '')
 => "rib-franzido-la-mandinne"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Rib Franzido - La Mandinne".gsub(/ - | /, '-')
  #=> "Rib-Franzido-La-Mandinne"
```

The regular expression attempts to match `" - "` or a single space, in that order. If a match is made it is converted to a hypen. If multiple consecutive spaces may be present you may wish to modify the regular expression as follows.

```
"Rib    Franzido    -  La  Mandinne".gsub(/ +- +| +/, '-')
  #=> "Rib-Franzido-La-Mandinne"
```

Answer (score 0):

In old-school/classic Perl-compatible Regex Style:

```
"Rib Franzido - La Mandinne".gsub(/\s*-+\s*|\s+/, '-')
```

This matches all types of spaces before and after dashes and multiple spaces/dashes.

Comment: When something is to be done with spaces you should use spaces, not whitespaces, in your regex; else you can get something like the following: `"Rib Franzido -  La.\nMandinne".gsub(/\s*-+\s*|\s+/, '-') #=> "Rib-Franzido-La.-Mandinne"`.